# Get the outer HTML of a detached JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a `html` node by `jQuery` (the sample is of tag `<input>` but can be of any type):

```
var x = $("<input>");
```

Then I add its attributes through a series of `.prop()` function:

```
x.prop("id", ...).prop("class", ...);
```

Now a certain plugin does not support JQuery object, but rather the `HTML` string so I invoke the plugin through this:

```
var n = plugin.method1(x.html())
```

Which I though will work but `.html()` returns an empty string. Although some said it will be resolved if I append it first on the DOM tree. How can I get its HTML string without appending it first in the DOM tree?

Comment: It does not matter that it's detached. `html()` returns the empty string because it has no contents. `html()` is the inner html, not the outer html.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1) to get [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property.

```
x.prop('outerHTML');
```

```js
var x = $("<input>");
x.prop('id', 'yahooooooooo');
console.log(x.prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit simpler to index the HTMLElement behind it and access the outerHTML property like this:

```
x[0].outerHTML
```